# Zapier: Split a string in array of objects

Tags: zapier

I have a requirement to split a string of comma-separated  userIds into an array of objects.

Transform

```
"123,456,789"
```

into

```
[{"id":"123"}, {"id":"456"}, {"id":"789"} ]
```

How can I do this in Zapier? We can use formatter and split the string into an array. But how can I get an array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do that by custom code steps:

```
https://zapier.com/help/code/
https://zapier.com/help/code-python/
```

Alternatively, one could create an app via our developer platform, which would let you create a private integration for your own Zapier account:
https://platform.zapier.com